# Git error: error: pathspec 'config_files' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

I am having some unusual problem with git. This is what I did

```
git add config_files
No error here

git commit config_files -m "first commit"
error: pathspec 'config_files' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any suggestions?

This is complete output.

git status :

On branch master
 Untracked files:
   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
   .bash_history
   .gitignore
   config.php.bak
   config.php_2augbak
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: What are the ** for at the end of `git add` and `git commit` ? I think there is no file named `config_files`, can you provide the output of `git status`?

Comment: I completely changed my answer after learning that `config_files` is a directory in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have files named config_files*, as you wan't to add the content of config_files directory you must do :

```
git add config_files/
```

then a `git status` will show :

```
new file : config_files/file1
new file : config_files/file2
and so on...
```

then you can commit with :

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Comment: Actually I have config_files named folder. That's why "git add config_files" didn't give any error.

Comment: Which files do you want to add ? the files in the config_files/ directory ? or the config.php* ?

Comment: I wanted to add config_files folder. This is code of one of my junior developer. When I looked I found that this folder is empty. Will this help?

Comment: Yes, so that's normal, cause git has no files to track... so nothing to commit...

Comment: So my error will not cause any issue? When I will create a clone, will I get this empty folder there?

Comment: Git can only store files, when you clone a repo, directories are created on the fly, as soon as it's needed (aka there's a file in it). The "hacky" way to have empty folders tracked by git is to add a `.gitignore` in it see [Git FAQ here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)

Answer (score 0):

One of your comments indicated that `config_files` is actually a directory. If that directory is empty, you cannot commit it, as there is nothing to be committed, since git only keeps track of files. You can `git add` a directory, but this just checks if there is anything in that directory to be added. You cannot commit the directory because there is nothing there. If you add a file to the directory, the `git commit` command will work as expected.

Comment: Sorry I did a typing mistake. I have edited the question. plz see now

Comment: Can you provide the complete output of the two commands as entered, then?

Comment: This is complete output: 
root/web# git add config_files
root/web# git commit config_files -m"first commit"
error: pathspec 'config_files' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: The `git add` had no output? That means it was successful. If that's the case, a `git status` should show it as staged (`Changes to be committed:`) and a `git commit -m 'your message'` should work without needing to specify a file.

Comment: Yes, it add was successful. But git commit did not. That why I said unusual. Thanks for trying. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does my completely revised answer shed any light on your situation?